# Store Data to Python Dictionary with Replicated Key-Value Pairs

Tags: python, python-3.x

Data:

```
names = ['Catching Fireflies', 
        'Spoonflower Color Map', 
        'Night Sky Stars Midnight Blue', 
        'Soft Meadow Floral', 
        'Just Jellies - Jellyfish', 
        'Ruth Bader Ginsburg RBG Bust - Black', 
        'Bees & Lemons - Large - Blue (original colors)', 
        'Mid Century Kaleidoscope', 
        'Native Eucalyptus Leaves || Edition 1 || Fabric Wallpaper', 
        'genevieve floral', 
        'William Morris ~ Pimpernel ~ Original on Black',... ] --> 84 items


creators = ['thestorysmith', 
    'spoonflower_help', 
    'at_the_cottage', 
    'sweeterthanhoney', 
    'katerhees', 
    'katerhees', 
    'fernlesliestudio', 
    'ceciliamok', 
    'erin__kendal', 
    'crystal_walen', 
    'peacoquettedesigns', 
    'ninola-design', 
    'neonborealis', 
    'anniemontgomerydesign', 
    'elladorine', 
    'hipkiddesigns',...] --> 84 items


fabric_names = ['PETAL_SIGNATURE_COTTON', 'SATIN', 'COTTON_POPLIN_BRAVA', 'PERFORMANCE_PIQUE', 'CHIFFON', 'ORGANIC_SWEET_PEA_GAUZE', 'POLY_CREPE_DE_CHINE', 'COTTON_LAWN_APPAREL', 'LIGHTWEIGHT_COTTON_TWILL', 'MODERN_JERSEY', 'COTTON_SPANDEX_JERSEY', 'ORGANIC_COTTON_SATEEN', 'LINEN_COTTON_CANVAS', 'ORGANIC_COTTON_KNIT_PRIMA', 'FLEECE', 'MINKY', 'DOGWOOD_DENIM', 'PERFORMANCE_LINEN', 'RECYCLED_CANVAS', 'SPORT_LYCRA', 
'CYPRESS_COTTON_BRAVA', 'CELOSIA_VELVET', 'PERFORMANCE_VELVET', 'BELGIAN_LINEN']


results = [('FABRIC_PETAL_SIGNATURE_COTTON', 1.75, 10.58, 18.22), ('FABRIC_SATIN', 1.75, 11.85, 19.71), ('FABRIC_COTTON_POPLIN_BRAVA', 1.75, 11.85, 19.71), ('FABRIC_PERFORMANCE_PIQUE', 1.75, 12.9, 22.65), ('FABRIC_CHIFFON', 1.75, 12.9, 22.65), ('FABRIC_ORGANIC_SWEET_PEA_GAUZE', 1.75, 12.9, 22.65), ('FABRIC_POLY_CREPE_DE_CHINE', 1.75, 12.9, 22.65), ('FABRIC_COTTON_LAWN_APPAREL', 1.75, 11.75, 21.66), ('FABRIC_LIGHTWEIGHT_COTTON_TWILL', 1.75, 12.9, 25.63), ('FABRIC_MODERN_JERSEY', 1.75, 13.29, 26.18), ('FABRIC_COTTON_SPANDEX_JERSEY', 1.75, 13.57, 26.42), ('FABRIC_ORGANIC_COTTON_SATEEN', 1.75, 13.83, 26.67), ('FABRIC_LINEN_COTTON_CANVAS', 1.75, 14.79, 27.59), ('FABRIC_ORGANIC_COTTON_KNIT_PRIMA', 1.75, 13.83, 26.67), ('FABRIC_FLEECE', 1.75, 14.79, 27.59), ('FABRIC_MINKY', 1.75, 15.29, 28.15), ('FABRIC_DOGWOOD_DENIM', 1.75, 15.83, 29.54), ('FABRIC_PERFORMANCE_LINEN', 1.75, 16.8, 31.58), ('FABRIC_RECYCLED_CANVAS', 1.75, 16.8, 31.58), ('FABRIC_SPORT_LYCRA', 1.75, 16.8, 31.58), ('FABRIC_CYPRESS_COTTON_BRAVA', 1.75, 17.23, 32.48), ('FABRIC_CELOSIA_VELVET', 1.75, 18.7, 35.46), ('FABRIC_PERFORMANCE_VELVET', 1.75, 21.5, 41.08), ('FABRIC_BELGIAN_LINEN', 1.75, 29.54, 58.17), ('FABRIC_PETAL_SIGNATURE_COTTON', 'N/A', 'N/A', 16.4), ('FABRIC_SATIN', 'N/A', 'N/A', 17.74), ('FABRIC_COTTON_POPLIN_BRAVA', 'N/A', 'N/A', 17.74), ('FABRIC_PERFORMANCE_PIQUE', 'N/A', 'N/A', 20.39), ('FABRIC_CHIFFON', 'N/A', 'N/A', 20.39), ('FABRIC_ORGANIC_SWEET_PEA_GAUZE', 'N/A', 'N/A', 20.39), ('FABRIC_POLY_CREPE_DE_CHINE', 'N/A', 'N/A', 20.39), ('FABRIC_COTTON_LAWN_APPAREL', 'N/A', 'N/A', 19.5), ('FABRIC_LIGHTWEIGHT_COTTON_TWILL', 'N/A', 'N/A', 23.07), ('FABRIC_MODERN_JERSEY', 'N/A', 'N/A', 23.57), ('FABRIC_COTTON_SPANDEX_JERSEY', 'N/A', 'N/A', 23.78), ('FABRIC_ORGANIC_COTTON_SATEEN', 'N/A', 'N/A', 24.01), ('FABRIC_LINEN_COTTON_CANVAS', 'N/A', 'N/A', 24.84), ('FABRIC_ORGANIC_COTTON_KNIT_PRIMA', 'N/A', 'N/A', 24.01), ('FABRIC_FLEECE', 'N/A', 'N/A', 24.84), ('FABRIC_MINKY', 'N/A', 'N/A', 25.34), ('FABRIC_DOGWOOD_DENIM', 'N/A', 'N/A', 26.59), ('FABRIC_PERFORMANCE_LINEN', 'N/A', 'N/A', 28.43), ('FABRIC_RECYCLED_CANVAS', 'N/A', 'N/A', 28.43), ('FABRIC_SPORT_LYCRA', 'N/A', 'N/A', 28.43), ('FABRIC_CYPRESS_COTTON_BRAVA', 'N/A', 'N/A', 29.24), ('FABRIC_CELOSIA_VELVET', 'N/A', 'N/A', 31.92), ('FABRIC_PERFORMANCE_VELVET', 'N/A', 'N/A', 36.98), ('FABRIC_BELGIAN_LINEN', 'N/A', 'N/A', 52.36), ('FABRIC_PETAL_SIGNATURE_COTTON', 1.75, 10.58, 18.22), ('FABRIC_SATIN', 1.75, 11.85, 19.71), ('FABRIC_COTTON_POPLIN_BRAVA', 1.75, 11.85, 19.71), ('FABRIC_PERFORMANCE_PIQUE', 1.75, 12.9, 22.65), ('FABRIC_CHIFFON', 1.75, 12.9, 22.65), ('FABRIC_ORGANIC_SWEET_PEA_GAUZE', 1.75, 12.9, 22.65), ('FABRIC_POLY_CREPE_DE_CHINE', 1.75, 12.9, 22.65), ('FABRIC_COTTON_LAWN_APPAREL', 1.75, 11.75, 21.66), ('FABRIC_LIGHTWEIGHT_COTTON_TWILL', 1.75, 12.9, 25.63), ('FABRIC_MODERN_JERSEY', 1.75, 13.29, 26.18), ('FABRIC_COTTON_SPANDEX_JERSEY', 1.75, 13.57, 26.42), ('FABRIC_ORGANIC_COTTON_SATEEN', 1.75, 13.83, 26.67), ('FABRIC_LINEN_COTTON_CANVAS', 1.75, 14.79, 27.59), ('FABRIC_ORGANIC_COTTON_KNIT_PRIMA', 1.75, 13.83, 26.67), ('FABRIC_FLEECE', 1.75, 14.79, 27.59), ('FABRIC_MINKY', 1.75, 15.29, 28.15), ('FABRIC_DOGWOOD_DENIM', 1.75, 15.83, 29.54), ('FABRIC_PERFORMANCE_LINEN', 1.75, 16.8, 31.58), ('FABRIC_RECYCLED_CANVAS', 1.75, 16.8, 31.58), ('FABRIC_SPORT_LYCRA', 1.75, 16.8, 31.58), ('FABRIC_CYPRESS_COTTON_BRAVA', 1.75, 17.23, 32.48), ('FABRIC_CELOSIA_VELVET', 1.75, 18.7, 35.46), ('FABRIC_PERFORMANCE_VELVET', 1.75, 21.5, 41.08), ('FABRIC_BELGIAN_LINEN', 1.75, 29.54, 58.17), ('FABRIC_PETAL_SIGNATURE_COTTON', 1.75, 10.58, 18.22), ('FABRIC_SATIN', 1.75, 11.85, 19.71), ('FABRIC_COTTON_POPLIN_BRAVA', 1.75, 11.85, 19.71), ('FABRIC_PERFORMANCE_PIQUE', 1.75, 12.9, 22.65), ('FABRIC_CHIFFON', 1.75, 12.9, 22.65), ('FABRIC_ORGANIC_SWEET_PEA_GAUZE', 1.75, 12.9, 22.65), ('FABRIC_POLY_CREPE_DE_CHINE', 1.75, 12.9, 22.65), ('FABRIC_COTTON_LAWN_APPAREL', 1.75, 11.75, 21.66), ('FABRIC_LIGHTWEIGHT_COTTON_TWILL', 1.75, 12.9, 25.63), ('FABRIC_MODERN_JERSEY', 1.75, 13.29, 26.18), ('FABRIC_COTTON_SPANDEX_JERSEY', 1.75, 13.57, 26.42), ('FABRIC_ORGANIC_COTTON_SATEEN', 1.75, 13.83, 26.67), ('FABRIC_LINEN_COTTON_CANVAS', 1.75, 14.79, 27.59), ('FABRIC_ORGANIC_COTTON_KNIT_PRIMA', 1.75, 13.83, 26.67), ('FABRIC_FLEECE', 1.75, 14.79, 27.59), ('FABRIC_MINKY', 1.75, 15.29, 28.15), ('FABRIC_DOGWOOD_DENIM', 1.75, 15.83, 29.54), ('FABRIC_PERFORMANCE_LINEN', 1.75, 16.8, 31.58), ('FABRIC_RECYCLED_CANVAS', 1.75, 16.8, 31.58), ('FABRIC_SPORT_LYCRA', 1.75, 16.8, 31.58), ('FABRIC_CYPRESS_COTTON_BRAVA', 1.75, 17.23, 32.48), ('FABRIC_CELOSIA_VELVET', 1.75, 18.7, 35.46), ('FABRIC_PERFORMANCE_VELVET', 1.75, 21.5, 41.08), ('FABRIC_BELGIAN_LINEN', 1.75, 
29.54, 58.17), ('FABRIC_PETAL_SIGNATURE_COTTON', 1.75, 10.58, 18.22), ('FABRIC_SATIN', 1.75, 11.85, 19.71), ('FABRIC_COTTON_POPLIN_BRAVA', 1.75, 11.85, 19.71), ('FABRIC_PERFORMANCE_PIQUE', 1.75, 12.9, 22.65), ('FABRIC_CHIFFON', 1.75, 12.9, 22.65), ('FABRIC_ORGANIC_SWEET_PEA_GAUZE', 1.75, 12.9, 22.65), ('FABRIC_POLY_CREPE_DE_CHINE', 1.75, 12.9, 22.65), ('FABRIC_COTTON_LAWN_APPAREL', 1.75, 11.75, 21.66), ('FABRIC_LIGHTWEIGHT_COTTON_TWILL', 1.75, 12.9, 25.63), ('FABRIC_MODERN_JERSEY', 1.75, 13.29, 26.18), ('FABRIC_COTTON_SPANDEX_JERSEY', 1.75, 13.57, 26.42), ('FABRIC_ORGANIC_COTTON_SATEEN', 1.75, 13.83, 26.67), ('FABRIC_LINEN_COTTON_CANVAS', 1.75, 14.79, 27.59), ('FABRIC_ORGANIC_COTTON_KNIT_PRIMA', 1.75, 13.83, 26.67), ('FABRIC_FLEECE', 1.75, 14.79, 27.59), ('FABRIC_MINKY', 1.75, 15.29, 28.15), ('FABRIC_DOGWOOD_DENIM', 1.75, 15.83, 29.54), ('FABRIC_PERFORMANCE_LINEN', 1.75, 16.8, 31.58), ('FABRIC_RECYCLED_CANVAS', 1.75, 16.8, 31.58), ('FABRIC_SPORT_LYCRA', 1.75, 16.8, 31.58), ('FABRIC_CYPRESS_COTTON_BRAVA', 1.75, 17.23, 32.48), ('FABRIC_CELOSIA_VELVET', 1.75, 18.7, 35.46), ('FABRIC_PERFORMANCE_VELVET', 1.75, 21.5, 41.08), ('FABRIC_BELGIAN_LINEN', 1.75, 29.54, 58.17), ('FABRIC_PETAL_SIGNATURE_COTTON', 1.75, 10.58, 18.22), ('FABRIC_SATIN', 1.75, 11.85, 19.71), ('FABRIC_COTTON_POPLIN_BRAVA', 1.75, 11.85, 19.71), ('FABRIC_PERFORMANCE_PIQUE', 1.75, 12.9, 22.65), ('FABRIC_CHIFFON', 1.75, 12.9, 22.65), ('FABRIC_ORGANIC_SWEET_PEA_GAUZE', 1.75, 12.9, 22.65), ('FABRIC_POLY_CREPE_DE_CHINE', 1.75, 12.9, 22.65), ('FABRIC_COTTON_LAWN_APPAREL', 1.75, 11.75, 21.66), ('FABRIC_LIGHTWEIGHT_COTTON_TWILL', 1.75, 12.9, 25.63), ('FABRIC_MODERN_JERSEY', 1.75, 13.29, 26.18), ('FABRIC_COTTON_SPANDEX_JERSEY', 1.75, 13.57, 26.42), ('FABRIC_ORGANIC_COTTON_SATEEN', 1.75, 13.83, 26.67), ('FABRIC_LINEN_COTTON_CANVAS', 1.75, 14.79, 27.59), ('FABRIC_ORGANIC_COTTON_KNIT_PRIMA', 1.75, 13.83, 26.67), ('FABRIC_FLEECE', 1.75, 14.79, 27.59), ('FABRIC_MINKY', 1.75, 15.29, 28.15), ('FABRIC_DOGWOOD_DENIM', 1.75, 15.83, 29.54), ('FABRIC_PERFORMANCE_LINEN', 1.75, 16.8, 31.58), ('FABRIC_RECYCLED_CANVAS', 1.75, 16.8, 31.58), ('FABRIC_SPORT_LYCRA', 1.75, 16.8, 31.58), ('FABRIC_CYPRESS_COTTON_BRAVA', 1.75, 17.23, 32.48), ('FABRIC_CELOSIA_VELVET', 1.75, 18.7, 35.46), ('FABRIC_PERFORMANCE_VELVET', 1.75, 21.5, 41.08), ('FABRIC_BELGIAN_LINEN', 1.75, 29.54, 58.17), ('FABRIC_PETAL_SIGNATURE_COTTON', 1.75, 10.58, 18.22), ('FABRIC_SATIN', 1.75, 11.85, 19.71), ('FABRIC_COTTON_POPLIN_BRAVA', 1.75, 11.85, 19.71), ('FABRIC_PERFORMANCE_PIQUE', 1.75, 12.9, 22.65), ('FABRIC_CHIFFON', 1.75, 12.9, 22.65), ('FABRIC_ORGANIC_SWEET_PEA_GAUZE', 1.75, 12.9, 22.65), ('FABRIC_POLY_CREPE_DE_CHINE', 1.75, 12.9, 22.65), ('FABRIC_COTTON_LAWN_APPAREL', 1.75, 11.75, 21.66), ('FABRIC_LIGHTWEIGHT_COTTON_TWILL', 1.75, 12.9, 25.63), ('FABRIC_MODERN_JERSEY', 1.75, 13.29, 26.18), ('FABRIC_COTTON_SPANDEX_JERSEY', 1.75, 13.57, 26.42), ('FABRIC_ORGANIC_COTTON_SATEEN', 1.75, 13.83, 26.67), ('FABRIC_LINEN_COTTON_CANVAS', 1.75, 14.79, 27.59), ('FABRIC_ORGANIC_COTTON_KNIT_PRIMA', 1.75, 13.83, 26.67), ('FABRIC_FLEECE', 1.75, 14.79, 27.59), ('FABRIC_MINKY', 1.75, 15.29, 28.15), ('FABRIC_DOGWOOD_DENIM', 1.75, 15.83, 29.54), ('FABRIC_PERFORMANCE_LINEN', 1.75, 16.8, 31.58), ('FABRIC_RECYCLED_CANVAS', 1.75, 16.8, 31.58), ('FABRIC_SPORT_LYCRA', 1.75, 16.8, 31.58), ('FABRIC_CYPRESS_COTTON_BRAVA', 1.75, 17.23, 32.48), ('FABRIC_CELOSIA_VELVET', 1.75, 18.7, 35.46), ('FABRIC_PERFORMANCE_VELVET', 1.75, 21.5, 41.08), ('FABRIC_BELGIAN_LINEN', 1.75, 29.54, 58.17), ('FABRIC_PETAL_SIGNATURE_COTTON', 1.75, 10.58, 18.22), ('FABRIC_SATIN', 1.75, 11.85, 19.71), ('FABRIC_COTTON_POPLIN_BRAVA', 1.75, 11.85, 19.71), ('FABRIC_PERFORMANCE_PIQUE', 1.75, 12.9, 22.65), ('FABRIC_CHIFFON', 1.75, 12.9, 22.65), 
('FABRIC_ORGANIC_SWEET_PEA_GAUZE', 1.75, 12.9, 22.65), ('FABRIC_POLY_CREPE_DE_CHINE', 1.75, 12.9, 22.65), ('FABRIC_COTTON_LAWN_APPAREL', 1.75, 11.75, 21.66), ('FABRIC_LIGHTWEIGHT_COTTON_TWILL', 1.75, 12.9, 25.63), ('FABRIC_MODERN_JERSEY', 1.75, 13.29, 26.18), ('FABRIC_COTTON_SPANDEX_JERSEY', 1.75, 13.57, 26.42), ('FABRIC_ORGANIC_COTTON_SATEEN', 1.75, 13.83, 26.67), ('FABRIC_LINEN_COTTON_CANVAS', 1.75, 14.79, 27.59), ('FABRIC_ORGANIC_COTTON_KNIT_PRIMA', 1.75, 13.83, 26.67), ('FABRIC_FLEECE', 1.75, 14.79, 27.59), ('FABRIC_MINKY', 1.75, 15.29, 28.15), ('FABRIC_DOGWOOD_DENIM', 1.75, 15.83, 29.54), ('FABRIC_PERFORMANCE_LINEN', 1.75, 16.8, 31.58), ('FABRIC_RECYCLED_CANVAS', 1.75, 16.8, 31.58), ('FABRIC_SPORT_LYCRA', 1.75, 16.8, 31.58), ('FABRIC_CYPRESS_COTTON_BRAVA', 1.75, 17.23, 32.48), ('FABRIC_CELOSIA_VELVET', 1.75, 18.7, 35.46), ('FABRIC_PERFORMANCE_VELVET', 1.75, 21.5, 41.08), ('FABRIC_BELGIAN_LINEN', 1.75, 29.54, 58.17), ('FABRIC_PETAL_SIGNATURE_COTTON', 1.75, 10.58, 18.22), ('FABRIC_SATIN', 1.75, 11.85, 19.71), ('FABRIC_COTTON_POPLIN_BRAVA', 1.75, 11.85, 
19.71), ('FABRIC_PERFORMANCE_PIQUE', 1.75, 12.9, 22.65), ('FABRIC_CHIFFON', 1.75, 12.9, 22.65), ('FABRIC_ORGANIC_SWEET_PEA_GAUZE', 1.75, 12.9, 22.65), ('FABRIC_POLY_CREPE_DE_CHINE', 1.75, 12.9, 22.65), ('FABRIC_COTTON_LAWN_APPAREL', 1.75, 11.75, 21.66), ('FABRIC_LIGHTWEIGHT_COTTON_TWILL', 1.75, 12.9, 25.63), ('FABRIC_MODERN_JERSEY', 1.75, 13.29, 26.18), ('FABRIC_COTTON_SPANDEX_JERSEY', 1.75, 13.57, 
26.42), ('FABRIC_ORGANIC_COTTON_SATEEN', 1.75, 13.83, 26.67), ('FABRIC_LINEN_COTTON_CANVAS', 1.75, 14.79, 27.59), ('FABRIC_ORGANIC_COTTON_KNIT_PRIMA', 1.75, 13.83, 26.67), ('FABRIC_FLEECE', 1.75, 14.79, 27.59), ('FABRIC_MINKY', 1.75, 15.29, 28.15), ('FABRIC_DOGWOOD_DENIM', 1.75, 15.83, 29.54), ('FABRIC_PERFORMANCE_LINEN', 1.75, 16.8, 31.58), ('FABRIC_RECYCLED_CANVAS', 1.75, 16.8, 31.58), ('FABRIC_SPORT_LYCRA', 1.75, 16.8, 31.58), ('FABRIC_CYPRESS_COTTON_BRAVA', 1.75, 17.23, 32.48), ('FABRIC_CELOSIA_VELVET', 1.75, 18.7, 35.46), ('FABRIC_PERFORMANCE_VELVET', 1.75, 21.5, 41.08), ('FABRIC_BELGIAN_LINEN', 1.75, 29.54, 58.17), ('FABRIC_PETAL_SIGNATURE_COTTON', 1.75, 10.58, 18.22), ('FABRIC_SATIN', 1.75, 11.85, 19.71), ('FABRIC_COTTON_POPLIN_BRAVA', 1.75, 11.85, 19.71), ('FABRIC_PERFORMANCE_PIQUE', 1.75, 12.9, 22.65), ('FABRIC_CHIFFON', 1.75, 12.9, 22.65), ('FABRIC_ORGANIC_SWEET_PEA_GAUZE', 1.75, 12.9, 22.65), ('FABRIC_POLY_CREPE_DE_CHINE', 1.75, 12.9, 22.65), ('FABRIC_COTTON_LAWN_APPAREL', 1.75, 11.75, 21.66), ('FABRIC_LIGHTWEIGHT_COTTON_TWILL', 1.75, 12.9, 25.63), ('FABRIC_MODERN_JERSEY', 1.75, 13.29, 26.18), ('FABRIC_COTTON_SPANDEX_JERSEY', 1.75, 13.57, 26.42), ('FABRIC_ORGANIC_COTTON_SATEEN', 1.75, 13.83, 26.67), ('FABRIC_LINEN_COTTON_CANVAS', 1.75, 14.79, 27.59), ('FABRIC_ORGANIC_COTTON_KNIT_PRIMA', 1.75, 13.83, 26.67), 
('FABRIC_FLEECE', 1.75, 14.79, 27.59), ('FABRIC_MINKY', 1.75, 15.29, 28.15), ('FABRIC_DOGWOOD_DENIM', 1.75, 15.83, 29.54), ('FABRIC_PERFORMANCE_LINEN', 1.75, 16.8, 31.58), ('FABRIC_RECYCLED_CANVAS', 1.75, 16.8, 31.58), ('FABRIC_SPORT_LYCRA', 1.75, 16.8, 31.58), ('FABRIC_CYPRESS_COTTON_BRAVA', 1.75, 17.23, 32.48), ('FABRIC_CELOSIA_VELVET', 1.75, 18.7, 35.46), ('FABRIC_PERFORMANCE_VELVET', 1.75, 21.5, 41.08), ('FABRIC_BELGIAN_LINEN', 1.75, 29.54, 58.17), ('FABRIC_PETAL_SIGNATURE_COTTON', 1.75, 10.58, 18.22), ('FABRIC_SATIN', 1.75, 11.85, 19.71), ('FABRIC_COTTON_POPLIN_BRAVA', 1.75, 11.85, 19.71), ('FABRIC_PERFORMANCE_PIQUE', 1.75, 12.9, 22.65), ('FABRIC_CHIFFON', 
1.75, 12.9, 22.65), ('FABRIC_ORGANIC_SWEET_PEA_GAUZE', 1.75, 12.9, 22.65), ('FABRIC_POLY_CREPE_DE_CHINE', 1.75, 12.9, 22.65), ('FABRIC_COTTON_LAWN_APPAREL', 1.75, 11.75, 21.66), ('FABRIC_LIGHTWEIGHT_COTTON_TWILL', 1.75, 12.9, 25.63), ('FABRIC_MODERN_JERSEY', 1.75, 13.29, 26.18), ('FABRIC_COTTON_SPANDEX_JERSEY', 1.75, 13.57, 26.42), ('FABRIC_ORGANIC_COTTON_SATEEN', 1.75, 13.83, 26.67), ('FABRIC_LINEN_COTTON_CANVAS', 1.75, 14.79, 27.59), ('FABRIC_ORGANIC_COTTON_KNIT_PRIMA', 1.75, 13.83, 26.67), ('FABRIC_FLEECE', 1.75, 14.79, 27.59), ('FABRIC_MINKY', 1.75, 15.29, 28.15), ('FABRIC_DOGWOOD_DENIM', 1.75, 15.83, 29.54), ('FABRIC_PERFORMANCE_LINEN', 1.75, 16.8, 31.58), 
('FABRIC_RECYCLED_CANVAS', 1.75, 16.8, 31.58), ('FABRIC_SPORT_LYCRA', 1.75, 16.8, 31.58), ('FABRIC_CYPRESS_COTTON_BRAVA', 1.75, 17.23, 32.48), ('FABRIC_CELOSIA_VELVET', 1.75, 18.7, 35.46), ('FABRIC_PERFORMANCE_VELVET', 1.75, 21.5, 41.08), ('FABRIC_BELGIAN_LINEN', 1.75, 29.54, 58.17), ('FABRIC_PETAL_SIGNATURE_COTTON', 1.75, 10.58, 18.22), ('FABRIC_SATIN', 1.75, 11.85, 19.71), ('FABRIC_COTTON_POPLIN_BRAVA', 1.75, 11.85, 19.71), ('FABRIC_PERFORMANCE_PIQUE', 1.75, 12.9, 22.65), ('FABRIC_CHIFFON', 1.75, 12.9, 22.65), ('FABRIC_ORGANIC_SWEET_PEA_GAUZE', 1.75, 12.9, 22.65), ('FABRIC_POLY_CREPE_DE_CHINE', 1.75, 12.9, 22.65), ('FABRIC_COTTON_LAWN_APPAREL', 1.75, 11.75, 21.66), ('FABRIC_LIGHTWEIGHT_COTTON_TWILL', 1.75, 12.9, 25.63), ('FABRIC_MODERN_JERSEY', 1.75, 13.29, 26.18), ('FABRIC_COTTON_SPANDEX_JERSEY', 1.75, 13.57, 26.42), ('FABRIC_ORGANIC_COTTON_SATEEN', 1.75, 13.83, 26.67), ('FABRIC_LINEN_COTTON_CANVAS', 1.75, 14.79, 27.59), 
('FABRIC_ORGANIC_COTTON_KNIT_PRIMA', 1.75, 13.83, 26.67), ('FABRIC_FLEECE', 1.75, 14.79, 27.59), ('FABRIC_MINKY', 1.75, 15.29, 28.15), ('FABRIC_DOGWOOD_DENIM', 1.75, 15.83, 29.54), ('FABRIC_PERFORMANCE_LINEN', 1.75, 16.8, 31.58), ('FABRIC_RECYCLED_CANVAS', 1.75, 16.8, 31.58), ('FABRIC_SPORT_LYCRA', 1.75, 16.8, 31.58), ('FABRIC_CYPRESS_COTTON_BRAVA', 1.75, 17.23, 32.48), ('FABRIC_CELOSIA_VELVET', 1.75, 18.7, 35.46), ('FABRIC_PERFORMANCE_VELVET', 1.75, 21.5, 41.08), ('FABRIC_BELGIAN_LINEN', 1.75, 29.54, 58.17), ('FABRIC_PETAL_SIGNATURE_COTTON', 1.75, 10.58, 18.22), ('FABRIC_SATIN', 1.75, 11.85, 19.71), ('FABRIC_COTTON_POPLIN_BRAVA', 1.75, 11.85, 19.71), ('FABRIC_PERFORMANCE_PIQUE', 1.75, 12.9, 22.65), ('FABRIC_CHIFFON', 1.75, 12.9, 22.65), ('FABRIC_ORGANIC_SWEET_PEA_GAUZE', 1.75, 12.9, 22.65), ('FABRIC_POLY_CREPE_DE_CHINE', 1.75, 12.9, 22.65), ('FABRIC_COTTON_LAWN_APPAREL', 1.75, 11.75, 21.66), ('FABRIC_LIGHTWEIGHT_COTTON_TWILL', 1.75, 12.9, 25.63), ('FABRIC_MODERN_JERSEY', 1.75, 13.29, 26.18), ('FABRIC_COTTON_SPANDEX_JERSEY', 1.75, 13.57, 26.42), ('FABRIC_ORGANIC_COTTON_SATEEN', 1.75, 13.83, 26.67), ('FABRIC_LINEN_COTTON_CANVAS', 1.75, 14.79, 27.59), ('FABRIC_ORGANIC_COTTON_KNIT_PRIMA', 1.75, 13.83, 26.67), ('FABRIC_FLEECE', 1.75, 14.79, 27.59), ('FABRIC_MINKY', 1.75, 15.29, 28.15), ('FABRIC_DOGWOOD_DENIM', 1.75, 15.83, 29.54), ('FABRIC_PERFORMANCE_LINEN', 1.75, 16.8, 31.58), ('FABRIC_RECYCLED_CANVAS', 1.75, 16.8, 31.58), ('FABRIC_SPORT_LYCRA', 1.75, 
16.8, 31.58), ('FABRIC_CYPRESS_COTTON_BRAVA', 1.75, 17.23, 32.48), ('FABRIC_CELOSIA_VELVET', 1.75, 18.7, 35.46), ('FABRIC_PERFORMANCE_VELVET', 1.75, 21.5, 41.08), ('FABRIC_BELGIAN_LINEN', 1.75, 29.54, 58.17)...] --> 2016 items
```

Scope:
There are 84 designs and creators each and 24 fabric types in which these designs are available my goal is to map these designs and creators with each fabric types associated with them respectively like:

```
(design_name, creator_name): --> 24 fabric types and their prices per meter.
(design_name, creator_name): --> 24 fabric types and their prices per meter.
(design_name, creator_name): --> 24 fabric types and their prices per meter.
```

Expected Output:

```
{
    ('Catching Fireflies', 'thestorysmith'): {
        'fabric_name00': 'FABRIC_PETAL_SIGNATURE_COTTON', 
        'test_swatch_meter_00': 1.75, 
        'fat_quarter_meter__00': 10.58, 
        'meter_00': 18.22
    }, 
    ('Spoonflower Color Map', 'spoonflower_help'): {
        'fabric_name00': 'FABRIC_PETAL_SIGNATURE_COTTON', 
        'test_swatch_meter_00': 'N/A', 
        'fat_quarter_meter__00': 'N/A', 'meter_00': 16.4
    }, 
    ('Night Sky Stars Midnight Blue', 'at_the_cottage'): {
        'fabric_name00': 'FABRIC_PETAL_SIGNATURE_COTTON', 
        'test_swatch_meter_00': 1.75, 
        'fat_quarter_meter__00': 11.85, 'meter_02': 19.71
    }
}
{
    ('Catching Fireflies', 'thestorysmith'): {
        'fabric_name01': 'FABRIC_SATIN', 
        'test_swatch_meter_01': 1.75, 
        'fat_quarter_meter__01': 10.58, 
        'meter_01': 18.22
    }, 
    ('Spoonflower Color Map', 'spoonflower_help'): {
        'fabric_name01': 'FABRIC_SATIN', 
        'test_swatch_meter_01': 'N/A', 
       'fat_quarter_meter__01': 'N/A', 'meter_01': 17.74
    }, 
    ('Night Sky Stars Midnight Blue', 'at_the_cottage'): {
        'fabric_name01': 'FABRIC_SATIN', 
        'test_swatch_meter_01': 1.75, 
        'fat_quarter_meter__01': 11.85, 'meter_02': 19.71
    }
}
{
    ('Catching Fireflies', 'thestorysmith'): {
        'fabric_name02': 'FABRIC_COTTON_POPLIN_BRAVA', 
        'test_swatch_meter_02': 1.75, 
        'fat_quarter_meter__02': 10.58, 
        'meter_02': 18.22
    }, 
    ('Spoonflower Color Map', 'spoonflower_help'): {
        'fabric_name02': 'FABRIC_COTTON_POPLIN_BRAVA', 
        'test_swatch_meter_02': 'N/A', 
        'fat_quarter_meter__02': 'N/A', 'meter_01': 17.74
    }, 
    ('Night Sky Stars Midnight Blue', 'at_the_cottage'): {
        'fabric_name02': 'FABRIC_COTTON_POPLIN_BRAVA', 
        'test_swatch_meter_02': 1.75, 
        'fat_quarter_meter__02': 11.85, 'meter_02': 19.71
    }
....
}
```

I've tried many things and this one is the closest one to my expected output but even this is not giving me my expected output:
Sample Input:

```
for name, creator in zip(names, creators):
    for idx in range(len(fabric_names)):
        Design_Name = name
        Creator_Name = creator
        fabric = results[0]
        test_swatch_meter = results[1]
        fat_quarter_meter = results[2] 
        meter = results[3]
        #print(fabric)
        

        if (name, creator) not in items_dict.keys():
            items_dict[(name, creator)] = {}
        itemCount = len(items_dict[(name, creator)].values()) / 4
        items_dict[(name, creator)].update({'fabric_name_%02d' %itemCount: fabric,
        'test_swatch_meter_%02d' %itemCount: test_swatch_meter,
        'fat_quarter_meter_%02d' %itemCount: fat_quarter_meter,
        'meter_%02d' %itemCount: meter})

print(items_dict)
```

reference csv_output:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JjiAKCGD1qLA2lad-ADegzPMtu8EBqhAjGcJdXVkS1M/edit?usp=sharing

Actual Code:

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd






headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'X-Spoonflower-Window-UUID': 'a9bc37a2-9eb2-4a1e-8ea1-fcee89347364',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Origin': 'https://www.spoonflower.com',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Referer': 'https://www.spoonflower.com/',
    'Sec-GPC': '1',
    'If-None-Match': 'W/95d6572c326b81ce98c7ae27ac449d42',
    'TE': 'Trailers',
}




def get_fabric_names():
    res = requests.get('https://www.spoonflower.com/spoonflower_fabrics')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
    fabrics = [fabric.find('h2').text.strip() for fabric in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'product_detail medium_text'})]
    fabric = [("_".join(fab.upper().replace(u"\u2122", '').split())) for fab in fabrics]
    for index in range(len(fabric)):
        if 'COTTON_LAWN_(BETA)' in fabric[index]:
            fabric[index] = 'COTTON_LAWN_APPAREL'
        elif 'COTTON_POPLIN' in fabric[index]:
            fabric[index] = 'COTTON_POPLIN_BRAVA'
        elif 'ORGANIC_COTTON_KNIT' in fabric[index]:
            fabric[index] = 'ORGANIC_COTTON_KNIT_PRIMA'
        elif 'PERFORMANCE_PIQUÉ' in fabric[index]:
            fabric[index] = 'PERFORMANCE_PIQUE'
        elif 'CYPRESS_COTTON' in fabric[index]:
            fabric[index] = 'CYPRESS_COTTON_BRAVA'
    return fabric



async def get_designEndpoint(session, url):
    """
    Get Design End Point
    :param url:

    """
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        response = await response.read()
        # print(response)
        json_response = json.loads(response.decode("utf-8"))
        extracting_endpoint = json_response['page_results']
        # extracting designId
        design_Id = [item['designId'] for item in extracting_endpoint]
        # extracting designName
        design_Name = [item['name'] for item in extracting_endpoint]
        # extracting creator_Name
        creator_Name = [item['user']['screenName'] for item in extracting_endpoint]

        return design_Id, design_Name, creator_Name

async def get_Fabric_Pricing_Data(session, url):
    """

    Extract all the pricing data with respect to Fabric type
    :param url: detail url
            :Return: json data
    """
    
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        response = await response.read()
        json_response = json.loads(response)
        #print(json_response)
        # Extracting Data
        try:
            fabric = json_response['data']['fabric_code']
        except:
            fabric = 'N/A'
        try:
            test_swatch_meter = json_response['data']['pricing']['TEST_SWATCH_METER']['price']
        except:
            test_swatch_meter = 'N/A'
        try:
            fat_quarter_meter = json_response['data']['pricing']['FAT_QUARTER_METER']['price']
        except:
            fat_quarter_meter = 'N/A'
        try:
            meter = json_response['data']['pricing']['METER']['price']
        except:
            meter = 'N/A'

        # summary = fabric + "|" + str(test_swatch_meter) + "|" + str(fat_quarter_meter) + "|" + str(meter)
        return fabric, test_swatch_meter, fat_quarter_meter, meter

async def main():
    urls = []
    tasks = []
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(headers=headers) as session:
        fabrics = get_fabric_names()
        design_Id, design_Name, creator_Name = await get_designEndpoint(session, 'https://pythias.spoonflower.com/search/v1/designs?lang=en&page_offset=0&sort=bestSelling&product=Fabric&forSale=true&showMatureContent=false&page_locale=en')
        for item in design_Id:
            for fab_type in fabrics[0:-3]:
                price_url = 'https://api-gateway.spoonflower.com/alpenrose/pricing/fabrics/FABRIC_'+ fab_type +'?quantity=1&shipping_country=PK&currency=EUR&measurement_system=METRIC&design_id='+str(item)+'&page_locale=en'
                print(price_url)
                urls.append(price_url)

        for url in urls:
            tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(get_Fabric_Pricing_Data(session, url)))

        results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        print(len(design_Name))
        print(len(creator_Name))
        print(len(results))
        return design_Name, creator_Name, results

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    fabrics = get_fabric_names()[0:-3]
    design_Name, creator_Name, results = loop.run_until_complete(main())
    items_dict = {}
    for name, creator in zip(design_Name, creator_Name):
        for idx in range(len(fabrics)):
            Design_Name = name
            Creator_Name = creator
            fabric = results[0]
            test_swatch_meter = results[1]
            fat_quarter_meter = results[2] 
            meter = results[3]
            #print(fabric)


            if (name, creator) not in items_dict.keys():
                items_dict[(name, creator)] = {}
            itemCount = len(items_dict[(name, creator)].values()) / 4
            items_dict[(name, creator)].update({'fabric_name_%02d' %itemCount: fabric,
           'test_swatch_meter_%02d' %itemCount: test_swatch_meter,
           'fat_quarter_meter_%02d' %itemCount: fat_quarter_meter,
           'meter_%02d' %itemCount: meter})

   print(items_dict)
    
    
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(items_dict, orient='index').reset_index(drop=False)
         df = df.rename(columns={'level_0':'designName','level_1':'screenName'})
         df.to_csv('scraped_data_1.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Sorry, if I'm not reading correctly, but whats the use of `fabric_names`? And where is `fabric_name00`, `test_swatch_meter_00`, etc. coming from? Also, you probably should use the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) instead of copy and pasting into your code.

Comment: @megargayu `fabric_names` are used to iterate over the results per fabric type.`fabric_name00`, `test_swatch_meter00` these values are coming from results lists of tuple.`results=[('FABRIC_NAME), test_swatch_meter, fat_quarter_meter, meter]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use list and dict comprehensions:

```py
names = ['Catching Fireflies', 'Spoonflower Color Map', 'Night Sky Stars Midnight Blue']
creators = ['thestorysmith', 'spoonflower_help', 'at_the_cottage']
results = [('FABRIC_PETAL_SIGNATURE_COTTON', 1.75, 10.58, 18.22), ('FABRIC_SATIN', 1.75, 11.85, 19.71), ('FABRIC_COTTON_POPLIN_BRAVA', 1.75, 11.85, 19.71)]

def well(names, creators, results):
    return [{
        key: {
            f'fabric_name{i:02d}': fabric_name,
            f'test_swatch_meter_{i:02d}': test_swatch_meter,
            f'fat_quarter_meter__{i:02d}': fat_quarter_meter,
            f'meter_{j:02d}': meter,
        } for j, key in enumerate(zip(names, creators))} 
    for i, (fabric_name, test_swatch_meter, fat_quarter_meter, meter) in enumerate(results)]
    
print(well(names, creators, results))
```

This will output

```
[{('Catching Fireflies', 'thestorysmith'): {'fabric_name00': 'FABRIC_PETAL_SIGNATURE_COTTON',
                                            'fat_quarter_meter__00': 10.58,
                                            'meter_00': 18.22,
                                            'test_swatch_meter_00': 1.75},
  ('Night Sky Stars Midnight Blue', 'at_the_cottage'): {'fabric_name00': 'FABRIC_PETAL_SIGNATURE_COTTON',
                                                        'fat_quarter_meter__00': 10.58,
                                                        'meter_02': 18.22,
                                                        'test_swatch_meter_00': 1.75},
  ('Spoonflower Color Map', 'spoonflower_help'): {'fabric_name00': 'FABRIC_PETAL_SIGNATURE_COTTON',
                                                  'fat_quarter_meter__00': 10.58,
                                                  'meter_01': 18.22,
                                                  'test_swatch_meter_00': 1.75}},
 {('Catching Fireflies', 'thestorysmith'): {'fabric_name01': 'FABRIC_SATIN',
                                            'fat_quarter_meter__01': 11.85,
                                            'meter_00': 19.71,
                                            'test_swatch_meter_01': 1.75},
  ('Night Sky Stars Midnight Blue', 'at_the_cottage'): {'fabric_name01': 'FABRIC_SATIN',
                                                        'fat_quarter_meter__01': 11.85,
                                                        'meter_02': 19.71,
                                                        'test_swatch_meter_01': 1.75},
  ('Spoonflower Color Map', 'spoonflower_help'): {'fabric_name01': 'FABRIC_SATIN',
                                                  'fat_quarter_meter__01': 11.85,
                                                  'meter_01': 19.71,
                                                  'test_swatch_meter_01': 1.75}},
 {('Catching Fireflies', 'thestorysmith'): {'fabric_name02': 'FABRIC_COTTON_POPLIN_BRAVA',
                                            'fat_quarter_meter__02': 11.85,
                                            'meter_00': 19.71,
                                            'test_swatch_meter_02': 1.75},
  ('Night Sky Stars Midnight Blue', 'at_the_cottage'): {'fabric_name02': 'FABRIC_COTTON_POPLIN_BRAVA',
                                                        'fat_quarter_meter__02': 11.85,
                                                        'meter_02': 19.71,
                                                        'test_swatch_meter_02': 1.75},
  ('Spoonflower Color Map', 'spoonflower_help'): {'fabric_name02': 'FABRIC_COTTON_POPLIN_BRAVA',
                                                  'fat_quarter_meter__02': 11.85,
                                                  'meter_01': 19.71,
                                                  'test_swatch_meter_02': 1.75}}]
```

---

Let's break it down for you to understand what's going on:

```
return R
R := [B for i, A in enumerate(results)]
A := (fabric_name, test_swatch_meter, fat_quarter_meter, meter)
B := {{key: C} for j, key in enumerate(zip(names, creators))}
C := {f'fabric_name{i:02d}': fabric_name, f'test_swatch_meter_{i:02d}': test_swatch_meter, f'fat_quarter_meter__{i:02d}': fat_quarter_meter, f'meter_{j:02d}': meter}
```

- The `R` token will iterate over each value `A` and its respective index `i` from `results`, inserting `B` into a new list.
- The `A` token will unpack the values `fabric_name`, `test_swatch_meter`, `fat_quarter_meter` and `meter`. If we take a look at some element of `results`, we'll see that it has this format:

```
('FABRIC_PETAL_SIGNATURE_COTTON', 1.75, 10.58, 18.22)
```

So, for this element, `fabric_name == 'FABRIC_PETAL_SIGNATURE_COTTON'`, `test_swatch_meter == 1.75`, `fat_quarter_meter == 10.58` and `meter == 18.22`.

- The `B` token will iterate in parallel over the names and the creators `key` and its respective index `j`, mapping each `key` to a value `C`.

By parallel, I mean that in the *n*-th iteration, `key` will be a tuple containing the *n*-th element of `names` and the *n*-th element of `creators`. So, in the first iteration, `key == ('Catching Fireflies', 'thestorysmith')`.

- The `C` token will create a dictionary containing the keys `fabric_name`, followed by the current index of `results`; `test_swatch_meter` followed by the current index of `results`; `fat_quarter_meter` followed by the current index of results; and `meter` followed by the current index of `names`/`creators`. Each key will map to its corresponding value in the current element of `results`.

Comment: Way too much code I think, try explaining the code you posted. This may help future readers understand your answer.

Comment: @keesjanbertus Added a better explanation.